# Median Voter Models in Two Dimensions (computing area of a bounded sector)

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, area, game-theory, voting-theory

I've been trying to work out a way of computing area for a two-dimensional median voter model I've been working on. A, B, and C are political parties that can choose where they want to be on the political spectrum (left/right, authoritarian/libertarian). Each party wants to maximise the area of the graph that they gain within the bounds of the political spectrum in order to maximise the number of voters they get (assuming political preference is uniformly distributed across the spectrum):

[image: A graph with three points labelled A, B, and C. Sections of the graph are coloured according to how close they are to each point: each point closest to A is red, each point closest to B is green, and each point closest to C is blue.]

[image: An image of a political spectrum graph. The axes read left and right for the horizontal, and authoritarian and libertarian for the vertical.]

Points can be moved around and cannot completely overlap. I want to know if there is an expression I can use to find the area of the zone closest to A / closest to B / closest to C thereby finding who wins purely based off

1. the coordinates of each party and
2. the size of the political spectrum box.

So far all I have been able to do is graph it out using perpendicular bisectors, but nothing further.

Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: The problem is that there are lots of cases to deal with – whenever one of the bisectors crosses a corner of the box you get a different expression. If you just want to explore configurations close to the one in your diagram, with the same bisectors crossing the same box edges, it shouldn't be too difficult to write down an expression for that.

Comment: Are you assuming that voters are uniformly distributed within each box?  I don't think that's realistic.  (And don't get hung up on the Political Compass.  The spatial model can apply to anything that voters care about: "Assume that voters care about the 'attributes' of candidates. These attributes form a multi-dimensional 'attribute space.'" "Since our model is multi-dimensional, we can incorporate all criteria which we normally associate with a citizen's voting decision process — issues, style, partisan identification, and the like.")

Comment: With one dimension, there is no pure equilibrium with 3 parties. So I'm not sure a pure equilibrium will exist when you have two dimensions. [I realise that this doesn't get at your question exactly, but it might be good to think about nonetheless.]